# Fatal error: Class 'Adapter_ServiceLocator' not found in /config/bootstrap.php on line 29 Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I have created a site in prestashop on my test domain, after moving the site on my main domain I am getting below error,  I have uploaded the backup files again but still getting the same error! 
 
`Fatal error: Class 'Adapter_ServiceLocator' not found in home/public_html/main/config/bootstrap.php on line 29`.
 Can you guys suggest me why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Where is Prestashop version?

Answer (score 3):

Found solution. Cleared all the cache from cache folder. and now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

remove cache/class_index.php and remove cache the browser, lucky

Comment: You should get someone to proofread before you post. It's very hard to know what you're saying currently.

Answer (score 1):

The autoloader uses the file `/cache/class_index.php`

You need to delete this file to trigger a reindex.